# unable to boot from flash drive

Tags: boot

So whenever I try to boot my flash drive with Windows 7 ISO on it, Ubuntu just opens up normally it goes to the purple screen and nothing happens.

Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your boot order, set usb storage devices first in the list. What ever is similar. Then restart. It should boot from your thumb.

This will be done in your BIOS. good luck.

Comment: Pardon me to ask, I actually do boot the usb flash drive because it allows me to choose the boot device do I still need to do this?

Comment: If you're able to boot from the usb, then it sounds liked you're having a different problem altogether.